# ¿Cómo puedo crear una dll en C# para posteriormente utilizarla en Genexus 18?

Tags: c#, genexus, sesiones, ldap, dll

tengo poca experiencia y espero por favor puedan ayudarme.

Tengo el siguiente código en C# (funcional) que probé en un proyecto de Windows Form:

[image: Mi código]

Es básicamente un login, pero para autenticarse en vez de consultar un usuario/contraseña en base de datos lo hace a través del directorio activo (credenciales de Windows, LDAP).

Lo que deseo hacer es crear una dll con este código en C# que posteriormente pueda consumir desde Genexus 18, en donde existe una pantalla de formulario como la siguiente:

[image: Pantalla Login que consumirá la dll]

el usuario ingresará su usuario y contraseña correspondientes y ahí es donde "consumiré" dicha dll, pero no sé cómo adaptar mi código.

¿Qué debo poner en vez del messagebox para devolver el acceso/error?

¿Qué tipo de proyecto debo crear (librería de clases, etc.)?

¿Qué más me falta o qué debo cambiar?

Nota: No requiero crear una interfaz gráfica en C#, ya que como lo menciono arriba, eso lo haré con Genexus 18, el tema es cómo crear la librería/código en C# y generar su dll (a partir del código que muestro) para después "consumirla" en Genexus.

Comment: Hola Jesus, bienvenido,  la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, evitar recibir votos negativos, y acceder a una mejor respuesta, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

Comment: puedes darle a crear proyecto con plataforma windows y seleccionas Biblioteca, la que se suele usar para crear dll es Biblioteca de clases (.NET Framework) que te crea un dll de lo mas normal que se puede agregar a otro proyecto pero no estoy seguro de que se le pueda agregar interfaz gráfica pero de todos modos todo lo referente a interfaz gráfica lo puedes hacer en el nuevo proyecto

Comment: @LPZadkiel No requiero una interfaz gráfica en C#, sólo la librería/código para que se genere una dll y después consumirlo en Genexus, pero gracias, por lo menos ahora sé el tipo de proyecto.

Comment: yo lo hice derecho en genexus, con la 15 fue, lo que no pude hacer es traerme los roles

Answer (score 0):

Y bueno, después de mucho investigar lo hice de la siguiente forma:

1. Adapté el código a un proyecto liberia de clases, quedó prácticamente como en la primera publicación.
2. Importé el archivo dll a Genexus 18 (desde Tools >> Aplication Integration >> .Net Assembly Import)

Después (aún desde Genexus) seleccioné la dll generada en C# y le puse el nombre de "operacion"

Como mi clase en C# se llama ldap Genexus toma el nombre operacion y lo concatena con el nombre de la clase, quedando "operacionldap".

3. Desde Genexus 18 utilizo 'operacionldap', igualando una variable booleana (&entra) que recibirá el valor correspondiente al método validasesion:

   ```
   /*Tengo una variable &entra de tipo booleano, si me devuelve true es
   porque las credenciales son válidas, si false, credenciales erróneas.*/

    &entra = operacionldap.validaSesion(&usuario,&pswrd) 
    if &entra
       //Continúa a la pantalla de inicio
    else
       //Mensaje "Usuario y/o Contraseña Invalida"
    endif
   ```